# Disable action center WinJS

Tags: windows-phone-8, winjs

I'm developping a WinJS application on Windows Phone 8 and I want to "disable" the action bar. I just want when I touch the top of the screen it doesn't show the action bar. I saw several games doing that : [image: Image example]

How can I do that with HTML or WinJS ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do two things:

1. Hide the status bar via [StatusBar.hideAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.statusbar.hideasync.aspx) method
2. Disable system overlays via the [ApplicationView.suppressSystemOverlays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.suppresssystemoverlays.aspx) property.

You need to do both things to minimize the Action Center popup thing.